# How to display accent text in android textview?

Tags: android, text, character, textview

**Situation:**
I want to display a german text in android textview. I use the default font, but the accents are sliped. (on the 'i' it's good, but 'ü','ä' etc. it's slipped away almost a character)

**Image:**

[image: http://postimg.org/image/u51ow53gz/]

**Question:**
What should I do to display accents good? What can be the problem?

Comment: Image doesn't work (ie doesn't show up on the website). :-)

Comment: How are you populating this textview? From XML?

Comment: use iso-8859-1 as encoding for you string

Comment: @ninetwozero Image added..

Comment: I download an xml from dropbox, after parsing, I call the: setText(Html.fromHtml(content)) method.
I do this (except the fromHtml part) other places in my program, but there I use custom fonts, and it works.

Comment: I found some 'ü' and 'ä' characters in the xml to be strange... If I have the cursor after an 'ä' and press backspace it's became an 'a'. I don't know how it's possible, but looks like an 'ä' is two character...

Comment: @user2313423 can you tell me the custom font name which you used?

Answer (score 0):

I set the **InputStreamReader** encoding to **MacRoman** instead of **UTF-8**. I supply this **InputStreamReader **  to GSON's **fromJson()** method. I still don't understand what's going on though.